# google drive api issue

Tags: php, google-drive-api

is there any issue with Google drive sdk and api (php client library latest).

i am modifying file in Google drive and then in q param date_modified> 'date before modified date of file'. difference between date_modified and the date i am sending is about 2-3 minutes  but i am getting empty result.
if i made this request after 5-10 minutes of modification time with same code i have used earlier, then i am getting actual result.  is there any delay to replicate changes to Google servers . anyone any idea about this?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Google Drive is a massively distributes system. Certain operations may take a while to propagate through. That can be a pain sometimes, sorry.

You should allow for this in your application.